# get the number of queries made on a page(inside my plugin)

Tags: wpdb

Is there an easy way to see how many queries you make on a page(inside my plugin)? As I dont want to many queries in my plugin.

Answer (score 3):

`$wpdb` counts the queries ran and saves the value in the `$num_queries` class variable.

> `$num_queries` 
>       The number of queries that have been executed.
>
> https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

All you need to do is retrieve it:

```
echo $wpdb->num_queries;
```

You may also be interested in the `$queries` class variable.

> `$queries` 
>       You may save all of the queries run on the database and their stop times by setting the SAVEQUERIES constant to TRUE (this constant
>   defaults to FALSE). If SAVEQUERIES is TRUE, your queries will be
>   stored in this variable as an array.

`$num_queries` will reflect all queries. The `queries` variable should have information enough that you can isolate and count only your plugin's queries, if that is what you want.